# Creating a google calendar using php api

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-client

I want to create a `google calendar` using php api, is it possible ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible !

```
$url = 'http://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars';
$data = array(
    'summary' => 'MyNewCalendarTitle'
     );

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

[code from this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

[link to doc for Calendar Insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert?hl=fr)

---

But it's way easier to use the [Google API PHP client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)

```
$calendar = new Calendar();
$calendar->setSummary('calendarSummary');
$calendar->setTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');

$createdCalendar = $service->calendars->insert($calendar)
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer this URL, it will help you

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v1/developers_guide_php

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/04/26/howto-google-calendar-api-php/

http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2010/09/new-json-format-for-google-calendar-api.html

http://mark.biek.org/blog/2010/07/addingdeleting-events-with-the-google-calendar-api/

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7420-PHP-Generate-links-to-add-events-to-Google-Calendar.html[6](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7420-PHP-Generate-links-to-add-events-to-Google-Calendar.html)